# Rename multiple files using python, file names are as Julian dates and need to be renamed to as calender dates

Tags: python

I have some thousand files and I need to rename them from a Julian date name to Calender date name.
e.g., 2000137.tif to 2000-05-16.tif

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `strptime` and `strftime` from the `datetime` module.

Demo:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime('2000137', '%Y%j'),
                                 '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

displays

```
2000-05-16
```

Just iterate on your file names and transform them...

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however it changed the file type (extention) from .tif to file

Comment: Worked fully now. I had to add few more lines to get what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using the following code:

```
import os
import datetime

path = r"directory"
for i in os.listdir(path):
    filename = os.path.splitext(i)[0]
    new = (datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y%j'),'%Y-%m-%d'))
    fileout = new + ".tif"
    os.rename(i,fileout)
```